# Why am I getting an access denied error while trying to use Google auth with Next-Auth and MongoDB in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, next-auth

Access denied error.

Hello, i was trying to do some project with next.js, following this guide (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wm5gMKuwSYk, timecode around 1hr 20m) I was trying to make google auth with next-auth.
The page with selecting google account is working.
Could you help me realize which steps i should take to fix the problem.
There are some files, related to BD and auth.

database.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let isConnected = false;

export const connectToDB = async () => {
    mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);

    if(isConnected) {
        console.log('MongoDB уже подключен');
        return;
    }

    try {
        await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
            dbName: "share_prompt",
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        })

        isConnected = true;

        console.log("MongoDB подключен")
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

user.js

```
import  { Schema, model, models } from 'mongoose';

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: [true, "Почта уже существует!"],
        required: [true, "Требуется почта!"],
    },
    username: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, 'Требуется имя пользователя!!'],
    match: [/^(?=.{8,20}$)(?![_.])(?!.*[_.]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9._]+(?<![_.])$/, "Имя пользователя не подходит, оно должно содержать от 8 до 20 символов и быть уникальным!"]
  },
    image: {
        type: String,
    }
})

const User = models.User || model("User", UserSchema);

export default User;
```

route.js file

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';
import User from '@models/user';


const handler = NextAuth({
    providers : [
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async session({ session }) {
            const sessionUser = await User.findOne({
                email: session.user.email
            })
    
            session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();
    
            return session;
        },
        async signIn({ profile }) {
            try {
                await connectToDB();
                // проверить, существует ли данный пользователь
                const userExists = await User.findOne({
                    email: profile.email
                });
                // если не существует, создать новый.
                if(!userExists) {
                    await User.create({
                        email: profile.email,
                        username: profile.name.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase(),
                        image: profile.picture
                    })
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Maybe the problem that i live in russia, maybe other, but i be thankful to every advice on that topic!

I tried to make new Clusters in MOngoDB atlas, changing password, checking .env for several times,
Using my browser vpn, and probably thats all, but maybe one more thing i tried to rewatch the video i send above for any errors i made (sorry for bad english xd).

Answer (score 0):

The signIn callback is missing a return statement. It's important to return true

```
    async signIn({ profile }) {
        try {
            await connectToDB();
            const userExists = await User.findOne({
                email: profile.email
            });

            if (!userExists) {
                await User.create({
                    email: profile.email,
                    username: profile.name.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase(),
                    image: profile.picture
                });
            }

            return true; // add this statement
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error("Sign-in failed");
        }
    }
```